# Why I get an Expression is not assignable error

Tags: c++

I don't understand why I receive an "Expression is not assignable" error from the following code:

```
class value_t {
public:
    int a;
};

class values_t {
public:
  std::map<std::string, value_t *> list;

  value_t * operator [] (const std::string & key) { return list[key]; }
  value_t * get(const std::string & key) { return list[key]; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  values_t values;

  values.list["aaa"] = new value_t(); // OK
  values["aaa"] = new value_t(); // ERROR
  values.get("aaa") = new value_t(); // ERROR
  return 0;
}
```

I don't see the difference between the second line of the `main` function and the other.

How suggested the solution is to change the return type in value_t * &

Comment: You probably want to return a reference to pointer instead of a plain pointer: `value_t *& operator []` and so on.

Comment: `("aaa"]` makes no sense. Note the `(` and the `]`.

Comment: @ODYN-Kon `values.get["aaa"]` makes no sense. If anything, it should be `values.get("aaa")`

Comment: Have a look at this for how you should overload the subscript operator. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Array_subscript_operator

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, you're correct, it was a hasty mistake on my end.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the get function. Is just a typo here. however I have correct it.

Comment: Also, you should probably avoid using `new` and `delete` directly. Prefer containers and smart pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`values.list["aaa"]` returns a reference to a pointer, which can be assigned to.

`values["aaa"]` and `values.get("aaa")` return the pointer itself.

Change the return type of those two to `value_t *&` and leave the implementation as it is.

Comment: Specifically, `values["aaa"]` and `values.get("aaa")` are [prvalues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue), which are expressions you can't assign to. It would be more accurate to say the one that returns a reference is the one that returns "the pointer itself". The other ones return the pointer's value, or copies of that pointer.

Answer (score 3):

`operator []` and `get` return `value_t *` by-value, that means both `values["aaa"]` and `values.get("aaa")` are [prvalue expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue), which can't be assigned.

> a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is non-reference, such as `str.substr(1, 2)`, `str1 + str2`, or `it++`;

You might check what the return type of [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), it's an lvalue-reference, then `values.list["aaa"]` is an [lvalue expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue) and can be assigned.

You can change their return type to `value_t *&` to solve the issue.